# Setting up a dropdownlist with a ViewModel with IEnumerable custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have changed my ddl to use the view model instead of viewbag, but I am getting this error:

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable'

In my ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<TimeZone> TimeZones
{
   List<TimeZone> timeZones = new List<TimeZone>();
   timeZones.Add(new TimeZone { TimeZoneName = "Eastern", TimeZoneOffset = -5 });
}
```

My View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("timeZone", Model.TimeZones as SelectList, new { @class = "ddl" })
```

my automapping

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.TimeZones, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.Timezones` is of type `List<TimeZone>` in your example.

`List<TimeZone>` cannot be converted to `SelectList` so the code `Model.TimeZones as SelectList` will return `null`.

Instead of the cast, use `new SelectList(Modle.TimeZones, "TimeZoneOffset", "TimeZoneName")`.